# exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x0) StockFish Swift Integration

Tags: c++, ios, swift, objective-c, stockfish

As we follow the below step to integrate the stockfish engine

1). Setup Stockfish engine library:  Original CPP Library : https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish

2). Setup "nn-axxxX2.nnue" files in project and folders

3). Create wrapper class for calling iOS Swift language to Objective-C (Wrapper class) and from  Objective-C to CPP class method

4). Once it build and run the app at time getting runtime error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0))

As you can see screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Is `StockFishWrapper` an object? If yes, should it have a `*`? Why is it not a property if `SFWrapper`?

Comment: you declared `sfwObj`, but didn't initialize it. Regardless of whether it is an object or should be a pointer (see above comment), but you need to call its constructor